# How to remove "This application was created by another user, not by Google."?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I use Google Apps Script make a form, but it will have a warning banner on the top, how to remove this banner >> "This application was created by another user, not by Google.", does anyone success ??? T.T

[image: image is here]

or need to pay for google apps?

Comment: According to this [google forum](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36752945), the warning is removed if you're using Google Apps for Business. There is no way of removing this through code from the API, at least none was mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: To combat abuse, Google expanded display of the "created by another user" banner to include all cases where either (1) a web app is published under a Gmail account and accessed by a user other than the publisher or (2) a web app is published under a G Suite account and accessed by a user outside the publisher's G Suite domain/customer.

So it is an intended behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63521070#comment4