# How to remove Warning "This application was created by another user, not by Google" in Google Apps for Education

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, warnings, google-apps-for-education

We set up a *Google Apps Script*-based Intranet in our organization, which benefits from Google Apps for Education. We've been using for months:

- doGet()
- HtmlService.createTemplate(...)
- Publish > Deploy as Web App and setting:

  1. "Execute the app as:" **admin@ourdomain.com**
  2. "Who has access to the app:" **Any member of ourdomain.com**

Everything worked ok up to now.

However today (July 7th. 2017) the HTML pages to be shown to the intranet users **include an inconvenient Warning added by Google** at the top claiming that *This application was created by another user, not by Google.*, which is really annoying. I understand that this warning must be shown when the Script is created by an unkown users. But in my case, I (the admin) is offering the Script to the users of my organization.

The conclusion in other past [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489365/how-to-remove-this-application-was-created-by-another-user-not-by-google) is that going Google Business or Education everything gets fixed. Unfortunately, it's not true anymore.

**Does anybody know how to avoid such warning in Google Apps Script for the users of our domain that run our own coded scripts?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script remove warning banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635284/google-apps-script-remove-warning-banner)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have a website just embed the google script into an iframe in your website just ensure in your doGet function set return to html.setXframeOptionsMode(HtmlService, XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Then in you website

```
<iframe scr="PASTE YOU GOO0GLE WEB APP LINK HERE"></iframe>
```

you can use css to resize the iframe as you like, i actually learnt this when watching a youtube video , in the ending of the video the instructor embed the google web app which he had created in the video in his website
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/OU2FAzC04fM)

He also left a link in the description of the video to His github page where he pasted the source code

Answer (score 6):

Bad news. Evidently this is the *intended behavior* from here on out.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63521070#comment4

> mc...@google.com    #4 Jul 11, 2017 04:42PM
>
> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>   To combat abuse, we recently expanded display of the "created by another user" banner to include all cases where either (1) a web app is published under a Gmail account and accessed by a user other than the publisher or (2) a web app is published under a G Suite account and accessed by a user outside the publisher's G Suite domain/customer.
>
> We understand that legitimate applications are also affected by this change, and we hope that broader display of the banner informs users while still allowing developers to deliver useful, usable applications.

I'm affected too. I guess I'll just live with it - only impacts one small web app for me. As a Nonpofits user I'll take what they can give. (A heads up would have been nice though.)

I realize others have more at stake than I do - I hope you can find a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We (the Education or Nonprofits) are subjected to Google's arbitrary decisions. We've done a lot of work on creating a low cost intranet to our organization and now some conditions have changed. That's so disappointing...  We can't trust Google. Definitely nothing is honestly free.

Comment: @JosepMariaHuguet you can also use blogger and simply remove all other HTML on the page at load time--its realy flexible

Comment: weird. I created an app just for me. Just I can use it, and it displays the message

Answer (score 4):

Same thing has been happening to us.  We have a G Suite for Nonprofit account (formerly Business) and have published webapps for several years via this account without the warning showing up.  Users began telling me yesterday July 6 2017 that the warning now appears across all our webapps.

I just created a test webapp where "Execute the app as" is set to an admin of our account and "Who has access to the app" is set to "Anyone, even anonymous".  As you can see https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxrKgPol_-eEskKzqRzN4WAMj-NiPm7iFavjZu-_vWtTJPyAEkK/exec does display the warning.

Something I just noticed, the generated webapp script's url now starts with *script.google.com/macros/s/* whereas before it would have included our organization name (e.g. *script.google.com/a/macros/rchsks.org/s/*).  So, the url will change if I go back to redeploy one of our existing webapps -- that will screw up several things, the least of which are bit.ly links pointing to the old url.

Not having these warnings appear was one of the benefits I read about when we considered signing up for what was then called a Google Apps account.  I'm an admin of our account and received several G Suite alert emails on July 6 2017 about problems occuring with Google Drive, Calendar, Hangouts, etc.  Maybe those are connected?

Answer (score 0):

How about teh Google site?

You have two options.

1. On a normal page, insert an embed component by url.
2. Create full embeded page by url.

Pros. Easy.

Cons. Cannot use url parameters.